# how to convert Office files to pdf using Aspose lib in Java

Tags: java, aspose, pdf-conversion

I am new to Aspose. All i know is, its a useful library for document creation,conversion etc. 
please guide me how can i convert any file(MS office) to pdf file since in my project the document uploaded has to be first converted to pdf then saved in some folder on harddrive. 
I have downloaded Aspose.Words and Aspose.Pdf for java.
Any example code or link would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: you can use apache poi, its aopensource. I used it and was successfully generated pdf files with same format as MS office files. I tried Aspose, its bit difficult, so i adopted apache poi

Comment: @developer I can't say anything about your experience with aspose but AFAIK Apache POI is free but not as much easy as Aspose.Another thing is, POI doesn't support images and special type of format as well as maintain document formatting after conversion to PDF.Where as we don't have any need to take care of these issues while using Aspose.Aspose is not free but it has these benefits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

- Aspose.Words for Java offers the feature to convert word files to PDF. For further details, please check  [Convert word file to PDF](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to++Convert+a+Document+to+PDF) Furthermore, it supports variety of document formats i.e. DOC, DOCX, ODT, RTF, EPUB etc. Please check [Supported file formats for more information](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/File+Formats+and+Conversions).
- Aspose.Cells for Java offers the feature to convert Excel worksheets to PDF. For further details, please visit [Convert Excel files to PDf](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Converting+to+PDF+Files)
  please check
- Aspose.Slides for Java offers the feature to convert PowerPoint presentations to PDF. For further details, please check  [Convert Presentations to PDf](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesjava/Converting+to+PDF+File)
- Aspose.Pdf for Java offers the feature to convert Text, Image, HTML, XML files to Pdf format.